# Countdown Column in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I think this is a new question as I have not seen this anywhere in search.
Is is possible to create a countdown in pandas dataframe?

I have a column [A] which shows either 1 or 0.
1 being a date when the event occured.
I like to create a column B which shows a countdown to 1 from 4days before the event occurs so it will show 5 4 3 2 1 and 1 on that day of the event.

```
A  B  
0  0
0  0
0  5
0  4
0  3
0  2
1  1
0  0
0  0
0  0
```

Any kind advise on this? :D

Comment: why it is not 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 ?

Comment: Hi Wen, that is possible too, its just an example

Comment: @JNg If you do not give a well-defined question, it is hard to for people to work on that.

Comment: Let me improve on it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
s=df.A.iloc[::-1].eq(1).cumsum()

s=s.groupby(s).cumcount()+1

s.mask(s>5,0)
Out[121]: 
9    0
8    0
7    0
6    1
5    2
4    3
3    4
2    5
1    0
0    0
Name: A, dtype: int64
df['C']=s.mask(s>5,0)
df
Out[123]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  0
2  0  5  5
3  0  4  4
4  0  3  3
5  0  2  2
6  1  1  1
7  0  0  0
8  0  0  0
9  0  0  0
```

Comment: @JNg yw~ happy coding

Comment: Hi Wen, I like to bring up an issue however, it works on my current dataframe with a single event.. but with a dataframe with multiple event it has show issues, I will edit and add below to show you